# AMD Catalyst Control Center reoccuring issue: Application Profiles regularly disappear and then reappear

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

I'm currently having a reoccurring issue where the 'Application Profiles' (custom driver-forced graphical settings per game) of AMD Vision Engine Control Center (AKA or formerly known as AMD/ATI Catalyst Control Center) sometimes disappears, causing me to lose my graphics settings in games. Some of these settings, I have been using for months. What's weird is, they occasionally reappear after disappearing for weeks, only two disappear again a few days later. I notice the disappearances and reappearances after a computer restart.

Because of this, my settings to force graphical settings in games whose in-game configurations don't allow a high-enough graphical setting or don't have a setting similar to the driver-forced one, have to be manually re-set from time to time.

**I would like to ask for solutions on how to back-up and restore these 'Application Profiles'** (so I could just restore them, in case they disappear again), **or to prevent them from disappearing in the first place.** This issue happens even if I have not changed my drivers and is reoccurring in multiple driver versions until the latest.

I noticed it happening from v12.2 until the current drivers (v12.10). My OS is Windows 7, 64-bit. My GPU is AMD HD 6750.

Screenshot of the Application Profiles tab, with all custom profiles gone:
[image]

Comment: There is a folder in like your user/App settings or something for the catalyst control center stuff where there's a file which has all your profiles. I don't recall where it is off hand, but if you search for it, it's not altogether hard to find. I used to back this up for this precise reason! See [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76837/amd-catalyst-control-center-has-stopped-saving-application-profiles?noredirect=1#comment146145_76837). However, I have found it to be too much of a hassle and stopped using the catalyst control center, now I use Radeon Pro for the same purpose

Comment: If you want to use radeon pro you should ensure you uninstall the catalyst control center first. I get far superior results controlling these settings with Radeon Pro.